# Button type submit is not working in IE browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, angularjs

I am doing html5 code for my application presently button type submit is not working in IE browsers any suggestions please.

My code is here:

```
<form id="rowform{{lrd.id}}" editable-form name="rowform" shown="lrd.isNew" onbeforesave="saveTable($data)"  ng-show="rowform.$visible" >
</form>
```

Button is out side from the form:

```
<button type="submit"  form="rowform{{selectedLrd.id}}" class="btn input-small btn-save" >Save</button>
```

Comment: `form` attribute is not supported by IE. Either put your button inside form or add a javascript event handler for IE.

Answer (score 1):

it is recommended that you use either ng-submit or ng-click to handle the submission in a program specific way.

see here: [Submitting a form and preventing the default action](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform)

I made your example work using ng-submit: http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

```
<form id="rowform{{lrd.id}}" ng-submit="save()" editable-form name="rowform" shown="lrd.isNew" onbeforesave="saveTable($data)"  ng-show="rowform.$visible" ></form>

<button type="submit"  form="rowform{{selectedLrd.id}}" class="btn input-small btn-save" >Save</button>
```

Comment: Had gone through your example but i want to put input tag outside of the form not inside

Comment: Look this fiddle when i place the Input tag outside of the form it will working in Chrome but not working in IE browsers 

http://jsfiddle.net/premraj10/U3pVM/2431/

Comment: We have some limitation, which is 'submit' button should be put outside of form, because we are using same button to submit multiple forms.